# On the product of $\mathfrak c$-many separable spaces

Tags: general-topology, product-space, separable-spaces

I already figured out how to show that the countable product of separable topological spaces is separable,  but I'm out of ideas when the index set has cardinality of $\mathfrak c$. My textbook says it is possible but gives no references. Any suggestions how to prove this statement?

In a less general setting, I would also be interested to see how a dense countable set is constructed to $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a related post on MO, in particular [G. Edgar's comment](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/20224/2-omega-1-separable#comment40198_20231) seems to be useful.

Comment: For R^R you can also check the following posts: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/488616/prove-a-space-has-a-countable-dense-subset
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420384/the-product-space-mathbbri-where-i-denote-0-1-has-a-countable-dense-s
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/526454/uncountable-product-of-separable-spaces-is-separable

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a special case of *Hewitt-Marczewski-Pondiczery theorem*, see e.g. Theorem 2.3.15 in Engelking's General Topology:

> If $d(X_s)\leq \alpha\geq\aleph_0$ for every $s\in S$ and $|S|\leq 2^\alpha$, then $d(\prod X_s)\leq\alpha$.

The $d(X)$ denotes the *[density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_function#Cardinal_functions_in_topology)* of the topological space $X$,
which is defined as $$d(X)=\min\{|D|; D\text{ is a dense subset of }X\}+\aleph_0.$$
I.e., $d(X)$ is the cardinality of a smallest dense subset, but if there is a finite dense subset, we put $d(X)=\aleph_0$.

This means that a topological space is separable if and only if $d(X)=\aleph_0$.

Some further references are given at [Planetmath](https://planetmath.org/hewittmarczewskipondiczerytheorem). Wikipedia article on [separable space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_space) mentions [Theorem 16.4c](https://books.google.com/books?id=-o8xJQ7Ag2cC&pg=PA109) in Willard's General Topology as a reference for the special case you're asking about.

---

A proof of this theorem can be found at in [this post](http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_a_topologist_2010;task=show_msg;msg=0487.0001) from Ask a Topologist. ([Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20150326181134/http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_a_topologist_2010;task=show_msg;msg=0487.0001); The post was written by [Henno Brandsma](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/4280/henno-brandsma).)

This theorem can  be used to show that there is an independent family on $\mathbb N$ of cadinality $\mathfrak c$; see
[Stephan Geschke](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/16330/stefan-geschke)'s [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48914/independent-families-of-subsets-of-mathbb-n-of-size-continuum)
and [paper](https://web.archive.org/web/20210614145006/http://www.hcm.uni-bonn.de/fileadmin/geschke/papers/IndependentFamilies_03.pdf).

Comment: Thanks, I found from Willard's General Topology exactly the theorem that I was looking for. That a product of $c$ many separable spaces is separable.

Comment: So the space $\{x\}$ is not separable? :-)

Comment: @Asaf: I've added the correction that density is $\ge\aleph_0$ by definition.

Comment: The link to Henno Brandsma's post no longer works, here is a [Wayback Machine linke](http://web.archive.org/web/20150326181134/http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_a_topologist_2010;task=show_msg;msg=0487.0001).

Answer (score 12):

For $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$, try viewing it as the set of all functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.  Then the set of polynomials with rational coefficients is a countable dense subset.  (Show that every nonempty open set contains such a polynomial.  It might help to first show that every nonempty open set contains a polynomial with real coefficients.)

Comment: Alright. Since the basic open sets in the product topology are of the form $\prod_{i\in \mathbb{R}} B_{i}$ where $B_{i}= \mathbb{R}$ except for finitely many $i_{1},...,i_{n}\in \mathbb{R}$, the only thing is then to show that there exists a rational polynomial that maps each $i_{k}$ to $B_{i_{k}}$?. For simplicity I guess I can assume that $i_{k}=k$ without any loss of generality?

Comment: @ThomasE.: Right.  Or to put it another way, given $x_1, \dots, x_n \in \mathbb{R}$ and open sets $B_1, \dots, B_n$, find a (rational) polynomial $p$ such that $p(x_i) \in B_i$ for each $i$.

Comment: Alright, got it. Thanks.

Comment: @NateEldredge Is $Q^R$ a dense subset in $R^R$? Where $Q$ is all the rationals in $R$.

Comment: @Paul: Yes.  (Try proving it!)  However, that doesn't help with this question as $\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{R}$ is not countable.