# Is $\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$ separable?

Tags: general-topology

I was trying to disprove (or also prove) whether $\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$ is separable. My intuition tells me it's a disprove. I thought perhaps proving that $\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$ is sequentially compact will assist?

Or maybe that won't help?

And my second question is in regard to $\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$ being regular? In here I have no intuition at all, unfortunately.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$? Is it the interval $[0,1]$ in $\mathbb{R}$? If it is then the set $[0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q}$ is dense and countable.

Comment: @S.S: I think he means all functions from $ [0,1] $ to $\mathbb R$

Comment: For your second question: A product of spaces is $T_1$, Hausdorff, regular, completely regular if and only if every factor has that respective property.

Comment: That $\Bbb R^{[0,1]}$ is separable is a special case of the Hewitt-Marczewski-Pondiczery theorem; see [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/97423/12042) for a statement of the theorem and references.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you intend $\mathbb R^{[0,1]}$ to have the product topology, it is separable.  More generally, the product of continuum many (or fewer) separable spaces is always separable.  This (or a more general result) is the Engelking-Karlowicz theorem; see http://blog.assafrinot.com/?p=2054 and specialize the theorem as stated there by taking $\kappa=\lambda=\aleph_0$ and $\mu=2^{\aleph_0}$.  (Note that, though you're interested in the product of separable spaces, it suffices to consider the product of countable spaces; i.e., it suffices to check that $\mathbb Q^{[0,1]}$ is separable because it's dense in $\mathbb R^{[0,1]}$.)