# A countable product of separable spaces is separable

Tags: general-topology, product-space, separable-spaces

This exercise is given in Munkres, but it is not stated in which topology that it holds. Do I take the product topology or box topology?

Additionally, I have a question on how to solve this problem. Let $A = A_1 \times A_2 \dots$ be the space, and let $B_n$ be the countable dense subset of $A_n$. Can I take $B = B_1 \times B_2 \times \cdots$ to be the countable dense subset, or do I have to be more clever than that?

Comment: Product topology, whenever the topology on the cartesian product is not specified, it's implicitly assumed that it's the product topology.

Comment: @Crostul does it matter if $B$ is open?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s the product topology, and you have to be a bit cleverer than that, because $\prod_nB_n$ is in general not countable.

HINT: For each $n$ fix a point $x_n\in B_n$, and consider the set of points of your $B$ that are equal to $x_n$ for all but at most finitely many indices.

In fact a stronger result is true: the product of $2^\omega=\mathfrak{c}=|\Bbb R|$ separable spaces is separable, but this is significantly harder to prove. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97413/on-the-product-of-separable-spaces) for more information.

Comment: Is it true that a set $E$ is dense in $X$ if every open basis element of $X$ contains points in $E$? Because if so, then this set is easily seen to be a countable dense subset.

Comment: @Schmidt: Yes, it’s true. If $\mathscr{B}$ is a base for the topology of a space $X$, a set $D\subseteq X$ is dense in $X$ if and only $B\cap D\ne\varnothing$ for each non-empty $B\in\mathscr{B}$. This isn’t hard to prove.